# javascript if else works in FF but not in Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, if-statement, cookies

Chrome and Safari ignores the cookie.  Works great in Firefox.  This is the code I'm using:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  if (document.cookie.indexOf('user does') != -1)    
  window.open("http://www.rochgaychat.com/chat/index.html", "_blank"); else ;
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answers from Alexandstein and RwwL worked in Firefox and Chrome but Safari executed the window.open even when no cookie was present.

Comment: I ended up using Alexandstein's code.  Also, I was ignorant of the fact that each browser seems to not be able to see another browser's cookies.  When I set the cookie in Chrome, Safari and FF doesn't show it when I look at the cookies they list.  Same thing happened when I set the cookie in Safari and/or FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to structure your code more like this:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('user does') != -1){
    window.open("http://www.rochgaychat.com/chat/index.html", "_blank");
}else{ 
    //Else code here
}
```

When I structure stuff like this, the code becomes a bit clearer for debugging and also now works in Chrome. Javascript is kind of finicky between browsers when using non-standard styles since certain errors that are raised in some browsers aren't raised in others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`if (unescape(document.cookie).indexOf('user does') != -1)`

Chrome/Safari might have that space in "user does" escaped as %20.

As an aside, this syntax is pretty odd; recommend you wrap the if clause in curly braces or put it on the same line as the if, and just omit the else entirely.